# Alter a view that refers to a non-readable secondary database

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, view

I have a database (DB1) that is not readable because it is secondary in an AG group.

I have another database (DB2) that is not replicated with the AG group. It contains some views that reference the first database. I need to periodically alter some views.

The error is:

> Msg 976, Level 14, State 1, Procedure vw_xxx, Line 4 [Batch Start Line
> 9] The target database, 'DB1', is participating in an availability
> group and is currently not accessible for queries. Either data
> movement is suspended or the availability replica is not enabled for
> read access. To allow read-only access to this and other databases in
> the availability group, enable read access to one or more secondary
> availability replicas in the group.  For more information, see the
> ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP statement in SQL Server Books Online."

I do not have these options:

1. Enable the readable secondary (lack of licenses)
2. AG failover (this is a DR site)
3. Add DB2 to the same AG (too large, I only want to replicate schema not data)

Are other options available?

I have 3 AG nodes. The DR is not readable because it lacks an active license to be readable. The `ALTER VIEW` occurs on DB2 at the DR site, referencing DB1 in that instance. I'm altering the views because I'm deploying changes with a dacpac in that DR site. I do not have licences to cover that DR site in an active way.

Comment: @HandyD Please do not answer in comments. It just makes unnecessary work for all concerned. See https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/is-the-comment-only-answer-acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a linked server on each AG node that references the AG listener?

You can then alter your view to query DB1 via the linked server using 4-part naming, instead of querying DB1 using 3-part naming. Then you shouldn't encounter this error as the linked server will redirect to the AG primary.